# Finding/analyzing data competitions that share the individual model's predicted outcomes?

Tags: prediction, kaggle, competitions

I would like to analyze past machine-learning data competitions, focusing on bias and variance of predictions. I thought I could look at past kaggle competitions, but unfortunately kaggle typically does not share the main output (predictions) of each model, making manual bias/variance comparisons impossible.

Are there other data competitions that do make available the predictions and the true test dataset? Could be either a famous data competition, or a  website/platform hosting competitions?

Thanks!